# Searching DataGrid for matching values

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I Have a data grid which can be queried based on a comboBox choice .

My code (shown below) is meant to search through the datagrid and if it finds a row with a matching piece of text it is meant to move the datagrids selected index to the corresponding row.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= DashBoard_DataGrid.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if  (DashBoard_DataGrid.Rows[0].ToString().ToLower().Contains(comboBox9.Text.ToString().ToLower()))
                {
                    value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                    // return dr.Cells[i].RowIndex;
                    DashBoard_DataGrid.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex =  dr.Cells[i].RowIndex;

                }
            }
```

However I am getting the following error

```
           Error    7   Property or indexer 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.RowIndex' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error ? searching online hasn't givin a solution

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change a `SelectedCell`'s row index, which is read-only. If you are trying to change the selected row, you need to set the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selectedindex.aspx) for the DataGrid.

```
DashBoard_DataGrid.SelectedIndex = dr.Cells[i].RowIndex;
```

Also, try changing `SelectedCells` to `SelectedRows`.

Comment: I've tried that previously but I'm getting the error 
Error 8 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user2311700, does [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9d9bf88e-ec2f-4e5d-ad44-a65de705fe16/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-the-selectedrow-in-a-datagridview) help you?

Comment: nope I've put it in but still getting the errors tried using Sayka's code which doesnt throw any errors but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.


DashBoard_DataGrid.ClearSelection();
DashBoard_DataGrid.Rows[3].Selected = true;
```

or if you want to select a specific cell, then

```
DashBoard_DataGrid.ClearSelection();
DashBoard_DataGrid[0, i].Selected = true;
```

this will select the first column of the desired row..